# error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ ; }' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, typescript

I am using Angular JS typescripts (data comes form backend springmicroservices.
Im developing new method called downloadExcel( )

In my component.ts

```
  Data: {
    //rownum: '',
   // requestID: '',
    student_id: string,
    date: Date,
    // 'month_id': ''
  };
```

In method =>

```
   ExcelDownload() {

    const subHeader1 = worksheet.addRow(this.headerData);
    subHeader1.getCell(4).value = this.Data(student_id. date); // I do want to retrieve student id and date on my cell (just 2 data)
```

Error I am getting

```
ERROR in src/app/Summary/Summary.component.ts(902,35): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ student_id: string; date: Date; }' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Any suggestions! Thanks

Comment: Isn't it because you're the type is 'student_id' and up there you wrote 'studnet_id'?
This call seems strange to me as well because the object has ';' separating 2 atributes (at least at the error line you wrote). To me it should be ',' instead of ';'.
Just guessing tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
subHeader1.getCell(4).value = this.Data(student_id. date);
```

With

```
subHeader1.getCell(4).value = `${this.Data.student_id} ${this.Data.date}`;
```

Data is not a function

And in your Data object studnet_id should be student_id

Comment: If i code like:  subHeader1.getCell(4).value = this.Data;  
Output
{"rownum":null,"requestId":null,"student_id":"0001","date":"2019-10-09T07:00:00.000+0000","month_id":null}

I do want to retrieve   student id 0001 
                                  date:  10/09/2020 ( in correct date format)